# The concept of range

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

For  a given value of  $u$,  the range  will  be maximum when   $\sin 2 \theta$  will be  maximum. Hence,  $\sin 2\theta  =  1 \Rightarrow  \theta  =  45°$,  this is the  condition  for maximum  range. $R_{max}  =  u^2 / g$.
How can this concept of Range be explicitly illustrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is true only in the case of no air resistance. For the case of air resistance, the angle for maximum down range is less than 45° and is closer to 30° than 45°. The equations incorporating air resistance which is proportional to velocity can't be solved in closed-form and must be determined numerically. Actually, the drag force is proportional to the square of the velocity but for ease of calculation resistance proportional to speed is often used.

If you ever watch the MLB channel you can't help but have noticed they devote a lot of time to discussing launch angle of a batted ball. Statcast has started charting all batted balls for initial velocity, launch angle, and range. A 30° launch angle is considered pretty large and beyond the angle for maximum down range distance.

Comment: What's this MLB channel?

Comment: Sorry, it's the major league baseball channel.

Comment: Please, can you explain better, yr explanation seem ambiguous to me, the aspect of air resistance and no air resistance needs simplification for better understanding. If I kick a ball vertically upward with an initial velocity, how would I consider the range at which I kicked this ball. I really wanna have full knowledge on this concept

Comment: In freshman physics, it is common to simplify problems to get concepts across. The solution you showed assumed no resistance due to friction with the air. In real-life, you do have air resistance and this affects the solution.  To fully understand you will need to attempt to solve the problem including this.  The internet should be loaded with examples of trajectories with, and without, air resistance.  It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

$$R = \frac {u^2 \sin 2 \theta _0}{g} $$ where $R $ is the range, $u $ is the initial velocity, $\theta _0$ is the angle of projectile with the horizontal.

Clearly, as you said, range is maximum for $\theta _0 = 45°$. This is why a long jumper takes a jump at angle of about 45°, so as to get the maximum range.

Have a look at this diagram:

[image]

As you can see, the range is maximum for 45°, and same as $\theta _0$ for  $90° - \theta _0$, because $\sin 2(90° -\theta _0) = sin (180° -2 \theta _0) = \sin 2\theta _0$.

If you want to more explicitly understand range, its difficult to write an answer here. Perhaps you have to practically see by making shots at exact 45° and other angles. But I don't think that will be quite possible.

Comment: Can you use an hunter and his Arrow for an explanation on range?

Comment: Firstly, you explain to me where you're facing a problem in understanding the range of a projectile. A range is the horizontal distance travelled by a projectile. What conceptual problems can you have on that simple definition?

Comment: I do understand range, but I just wanna know when it is @45° or above 45° ... Am really sorry Sir, just wanna have deep knowledge on it.

Comment: As the drawing shows, it will not be above 45 degrees.  For a football or baseball, air resistance is important and will lower the angle to below 45 degrees.